# ConTeXt : how to get dingbat glyphs?

Tags: symbols, context

I am trying to use symbols, as explained in [this wiki page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols), but I can't get the glyphs I want. For instance, the wiki page says in the "Predefined sets" section there is a unicode set

> uni : Unicode symbols (including Zapf Dingbats, lots of sets...)

but I can't get a glyph from it. I tried this (with the unicode hex code) :

```
\definesymbol[cross][\getglyph{uni}{\char"271E}]
```

The compilation reads the following lines :

```
fonts           > defining > font with asked name 'uni' is not found using lookup 'file'
fonts           > defining > unknown font 'uni', loading aborted
```

So that I suppose there is something wrong with my installation (ConTeXt Standalone, updated today), but I can't find how to install this symbol package.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The list of symbol sets on the wiki is outdated because it refers to old MkII files which rely on pdfTeX as engine. When you use MkIV or LMTX you can take a look at the fontawesome symbols or define a fallback for you main font to get the symbols.

Comment: You can get a document with a symbols for fontawesome with the following example: `\usesymbols[fontawesome]
\starttext
\showsymbolset[fontawesome]
\stoptext`

Comment: I like to use [FontDrop!](https://fontdrop.info/) to see what glyphs are in a font. KeenWrite's [Containerfile](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/blob/master/Containerfile) shows a way to install fonts. Even though the fonts are installed _before_ ConTeXt, you can rebuild the font cache on your system using the link in my previous comment, after ConTeXt is installed.

Comment: A. Licari, did you find a working solution that you'd be willing to post as an answer to help other passersby?

Comment: @DaveJarvis Not really... I have just found that FontDrop is a great tool but still not really understood how to add fonts, and I didn't really have time to work on this recently...